# can't load the image on canvas (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to load the image on canvas but it's not working:(
I checked functions and variables much time but I couldn't find any errors.
Help me to find the reasons why it can't be loaded.
When I run it on the tomcat server, only the canvas with aliceblue color is shown.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Print image and text</title>
<script>
function drawPicture(ctx) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.addEventListener('load', function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 20, 20, 100, 100);
        ctx.font = "50px forte";
        ctx.strokeStyle="blue";
        ctx.fillStyle = "violet";
        ctx.strokeText("Spongebob", 20, 100);
        ctx.fillText("Spongebob", 20, 100);
    }, false);
    img.src = "spongebob.png";
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Print image and text</h3>
<hr>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="130" 
        style="background-color:aliceblue"></canvas>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
drawPicture(context);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check the network panel of your dev tools and verify your resource is fetched correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, here is an example with a different image...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="130"></canvas>
  <script>
    function drawPicture(ctx) {
      var img = new Image();
      img.addEventListener('load', function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 20, 20, 100, 100);
        ctx.font = "50px forte";
        ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
        ctx.fillStyle = "violet";
        ctx.strokeText("Spongebob", 20, 100);
        ctx.fillText("Spongebob", 20, 100);
      }, false);
      img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFBxY.png";
    }
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    drawPicture(context);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Only thing could be that the image you are trying to load does not exist...
As @Kaiido mentioned in the comments you need to debug this, check in your browser developer tools see if the image is loading correctly.

You should see something like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

instead of `image.addEventListener`, try doing `image.onload`?

Answer (score -1):

You can instead of using the load event in the image, try adding the image directly on the canvas.

```js
function drawPicture(ctx) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "spongebob.png";
    ctx.drawImage(img, 20, 20, 100, 100);
    ctx.font = "50px forte";
    ctx.strokeStyle="blue";
    ctx.fillStyle = "violet";
    ctx.strokeText("Spongebob", 20, 100);
    ctx.fillText("Spongebob", 20, 100);
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
drawPicture(context);
```

```html
<h3>Print image and text</h3>
<hr>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="130" 
        style="background-color:aliceblue"></canvas>
```

Comment: This is incorrect! you need the load event or you risk executing drawImage without the image fully loaded and nothing will show